# Do many users turn off cookies?

Tags: cookie

Just how generally prevalent is it that users have cookies disabled in their browsers?

I want to set a cookie during a user's session so that all the pages know that the presence of a particular software program (required for certain functions on my site) has been detected.  I can't really require cookies in this website, but cookies would be the easiest way to do what I need to do.

So, do many users turn cookies off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Quora](http://www.quora.com/Web-Marketing/What-is-the-percent-of-cookie-disabled-users-online) has a good answer for this:

> I imagine it's quite difficult to develop a study without significant
>   biases.
>
> But here's one ([A study of Internet users' cookie and javascript
>   settings](http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/84-a-study-of-internet-users-cookie-and-javascript-settings)) that found in a sample of 13,500 visitors to their
>   website 10% seemed to have 3rd party cookies turned off with only 3.7%
>   disabling all cookies. They also looked at javascript disabling, but
>   found few did that... even fewer during weekdays, presumably because
>   so many web-based applications require javascript. That study was done
>   in 2009.
>
> This page ([Percent of internet users who turn cookies off](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/511835.html)) from
>   2005 references a more formal report in 2000 that suggested back then
>   around 10% of users disabled cookies. They were shocked at how low it
>   was.
>
> This page ([How many people reject cookies?](http://www.marketingfacts.nl/berichten/how_many_people_reject_cookies/)) references a report
>   in 2001 that put the figure much lower, around 0.7%.
>
> This page ([Study: Consumers Delete Cookies at Surprising Rate](http://www.clickz.com/clickz/news/1691871/study-consumers-delete-cookies-surprising-rate))
>   mostly talks about the frequency with which people delete cookies, but
>   also mentions a report that put the rejection of 3rd party cookies at
>   28%.
>
> This page ([Cookie & Tracking Technology Pages](http://www.grc.com/cookies/stats.htm)) breaks it down by
>   browser, saying the stats are from "last week" but it is unclear to me
>   if these are live stats that are updated weekly so "last week" could
>   mean anything. Of their 57,000+ sample size they found negligible
>   rejection of 1st party cookies and a 15% rejection of 3rd party
>   cookies.
>
> This page ([As Industry Confronts 'Do Not Track,' Startup Announces
>   Mobile Behavioral Ad Targeting Without Cookies](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/as-industry-confronts-do-not-track-startup-announces-mobile-behavioral-ad-targeting-without-cookies-172251771.html)) talks about a
>   study in 2005 which suggested 25% of users in their study block or
>   disable cookies, but I rather suspect they are referring to 3rd party
>   cookies.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm glad you knew where to look, because I sure didn't!

Comment: Google Chrome seems to block _3rd party_ cookies by default, so I imagine this figure to be quite high, and increasing.

Comment: Further to my comment above (from 3 years ago!?)... I don't think Google Chrome now blocks 3rd party cookies by default (although I'm still pretty sure it did at some point in the past).