# Most widespread cookies

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, cookie

What are the most widespread cookies among population? One example could be [_ga cookie](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/76216/how-to-read-user-unique-code-from-ga-cookie), but are there any others public cookies that almost everyone has in his/her browser?

Why am I asking?
I want to keep track about people who visit my site. If [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77088/what-is-the-percentage-of-users-that-block-cookies-in-their-web-browser) or [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/do-many-users-turn-off-cookies) are true, then IMHO a mixture of several third-party general used cookies could make a good fingerprint of my visitor.

Comment: You can only access your cookies. Are you having a specific problem? Most users do not block cookies. Generally, only the tech savvy will block cookies and even then, only a sub-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not really matter what the most widespread cookie is as you can only access cookies set by your site for your site. Trying to access other cookies is classified a security issue and so browsers won't allow you to access cookies that have not been set under your domain name.

In other words if your domain is example.com and you set your cookies at that level then you can access the cookies from

- example.com
- www.example.com
- blog.example.com
- etc

But you can't access any cookies from other domains such as example2.com, notmydomain.com, etc.